# Flutter TextField cursor is not vertically center when there is nothing input

Tags: flutter, dart

I set the `cursorHeight` property of flutter's `TextField`, but when there **is no content** in the `TextField`, the cursor cannot be vertically centered with the `hintText`, as shown in the following figure:

[image]

However, when there **is content** in the `TextField`, the content text and the cursor will be vertically centered, as shown in the following figure:

[image]

This is my code:

```dart
TextField(
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Type here to add a quick TODO...",
    enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
    focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
  ),
  cursorHeight: 25,
  cursorRadius: Radius.circular(10),
  maxLines: 1,
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 15,
  ),
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      _typedContent = value;
    });
  },
```

Is there any way to make the cursor center vertically even when there is no text input?

Comment: same here, find a solution>

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you can remove the `cursorHeight` property if it is not a must.

Second option is using the `height` property of your TextStyle. As far as I remember you can start trying with following ratio: cursorHeight/textSize. In any case I recommend you reading about [height property of TextStyle.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/height.html)

```
style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 15,
          height: 25/15
        ),
```

Answer (score 2):

## Custom the height of the text ([height property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/height.html))

```
  TextField(
    style: TextStyle(
      height: 1.5
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this but i found an easy solution.
NOTE: The Cursor vertical alignment is related to a few things.

1. cursorHeight
2. the Text height
3. the Text fontSize

The cursor grow upward by setting the (3) fontSize while it grows downward by setting the (1) cursorHeight. To notice this and be able to adjust properly to vertically center the cursor with the hintText you need to:
First set (2) the Text height to 1.
Second grow the cursor both upward and downward until u are satisfied with how it looks centered with the hinttext.

Here is an example:

```
TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Search',
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 19,
        ),
      ),
      cursorHeight: 17,
      style: TextStyle(
        height: 1,
        fontSize: 21,
      ),
    );
```

And the result:
[Center Cursor with Search hint text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQyA5.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following properties to your text field:

1- textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center

2- In InputDecoration add contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0)

3- In IconButton add padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0)

[image]

```
TextField(
  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
    prefixIcon: Icon(
      Icons.search,
    ),
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 20,
    ),
    suffixIcon: IconButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
      icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
      onPressed: null,
    ),
    hintText: "Search"
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I addressed it by setting

```
textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
```

and now it seems the cursor is vertically centered.

If you've already adjusted things like font size but still want to display the cursor at the top, this might solve the issue.